# Deduce non present template parameter from return function

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

hope you guys can help with this:
I have the following function that should return an object Foo, in this case with a specific types:

```
Foo<int,bool> make_my_foo_object() {
  return make_foo(10);
}
```

in my Foo class I have:

```
template <class A, class B>
  struct Foo {
    Foo(A aa): a(aa) {}
    Foo(B bb): b(bb) {}
    A a;
    B b;
  };
```

Then, in my make_foo function I have:

```
template<typename A, class B>
    Foo<A,B> make_foo(A a) {
        return Foo<A,B>(a); // this should call the Foo(A) ctor
    };
```

I know this is not possible as there is no way in this simple implementation that `B` can be infer from the return type of make_foo.

The `make_my_foo_object` make not much sense in this context, but the whole idea is dealing with template params that cannot be deduced as they are missed.

What I'm trying to avoid is to specify the types in the  *return make_foo`<int, bool>`(10);* in the `make_my_foo_object` function.

Do you guys think there is a possible workaround to this? or it's a no-go!

Any help or information will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: First, why do you want to avoid it passing those parameters?  You have them right there the line above.  I ask this because I can produce solutions, but the solutions are likely to not help you *if I don't understand your real problem*.  That would be a waste of my time (generating a solution that doesn't help you).  Can you describe a practical problem you are trying to solve with this request?

Comment: And why do you not just write `return {10};`. How is the extra `make_foo` call useful

Comment: In this example the template arguments are small. The real example could be more  tricky and not just doing `make_foo<x,y>()` . As template arguments cannot be deduced from their constructors I need this make workaround as it's a well known idiom to co over this issue. the issue is clear to me, but the question is how to go(if possible) go over that. 
if you need to create a tuple with 10 different types in it, you will avoid to type all then types. 
Thanks.

Comment: So is your main question how to deduce the type params in `make_foo`, or how to avoid re-typing them in `make_my_foo_object`?

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb That's what I'm doing currently and probably it will be what I will end up doing by default, but I wan't to make that call there. it can also be wrapped into a macro `#define bla(x) { z }`. But my real goal is understand how to go over this.

Comment: @Useless avoid the explicit types in the make_foo(). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class...Ts>
struct make_something_t {
  std::tuple<Ts...> data;
  template<class T, std::size_t...Is>
  T make(std::index_sequence<Is...>) && {
    return T( std::get<Is>(std::move(data))... );
  }
  template<class T>
  operator T()&&{
    return std::move(*this).template make<T>(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{});
  }
};
template<class...Ts>
make_something_t<Ts...> make_something( Ts&&...ts ) {
  return {std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)};
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e956ca8bf5df5c4).

`make_something(args...)` doesn't make anything.  Instead, you can use it to construct (almost) anything, and it uses `args...` to do the construction of whatever type you construct from it.

This may not be a great idea, but it deduces the type of object you make from by what object you construct from it.

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm trying to avoid is to specify the types in the return make_foo(10); in the make_my_foo_object function.

Something like this probably works for you (minimal, working example in C++14):

```
template <class A, class B>
struct Foo {
    Foo(A aa): a(aa) {}
    Foo(B bb): b(bb) {}
    A a;
    B b;
};

template<typename A, class B>
Foo<A,B> make_foo(A a) {
    return Foo<A,B>(a);
}

struct W {
    template<typename A, typename B>
    operator Foo<A, B>() {
        return make_foo<A, B>(10);
    }
};

auto make_my_foo_object() {
    return W{};
}

int main() {
    Foo<int, bool> foo1 = make_my_foo_object();
    Foo<int, char> foo2 = make_my_foo_object();
}
```

Template parameters are deduced by the operator present in `W`:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
operator Foo<A, B>() {
    return make_foo<A, B>(10);
}
```

For you tagged it as C++14, `auto` return type is allowed and it does the rest.
As requested (if I got correctly your request) `make_my_foo_object` no longer has template parameters, that is it's not a function template.

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern is avoiding repetition of the hardcoded type params, you can just give them names like so:

```
template <typename A=int, typename B=bool>
Foo<A,B> make_my_foo_object() {
  return make_foo<A,B>(10);
}
```

That is, the decision about what types to use for A and B simply moves from the return type, to the template parameter list.

Comment: It isn't using the bool param at all at the moment, and B isn't involved in any conversion. What do you mean?

Comment: Just removed my previous comment, now looking at it better, it make sense but there are two things I'm trying to avoid, if you have to write your own `make_my_foo_object` function, then you have to deal with the template declaration in your function and that's not what I want to be doing.  I'm trying to avoid you to be writing the template signature in your functions. Thanks

Comment: _in your function_ - in **what** function? In the caller? That doesn't need to specify the params, that's the whole reason for defaulting them. In `make_my_foo_object` at all? You have to specify the types somewhere, you just had them in the return type before. Or you just want to avoid typing the `template` keyword for some reason?